# Can BRDF be used to reconstruct an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I know that BRDF can be used to render images, but can BRDF be used to reconstruct an image?

Here is a scenario:
I have an image + geometric and radiometric calibrations, using these I can get the BRDF. Is there a way then to use the BRDF to reconstruct the original image?

Comment: Probably, but I guess the solution is part of a research paper and might be slightly out of scope here.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks for your reply. If it is possible, do you have any suggestion of papers I could read or forums where I could discuss this further?

Comment: I would just google it and start from there. There is a paper called "Image-Based BRDF Reconstruction" and it is among the top 3 google results.